# how to get a fixed header with navigation inside

Tags: html, css, css-position, navbar

I'm new to the whole HTML and CSS thing, but have been doing okay so far.

Now I need to stick my header to the top, so when scrolling down it stays to the top and the other content is scrolled through.

I've been googling and searching a lot, and cannot find the best solution and I'm hoping you can help me!

Just for info I'm using the 960 grid.

Here is the code:

```
    <div class="container_12">
    <header class="fixed">
        <img src="img/logolangt.jpg" alt="MB it logo" class="grid_12"/>
        <nav class="grid_12" id="mainnav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="career.html">Career</a></li>
                <li><a href="clients.html">Clients</a></li>
                <li><a href="about us.html">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav class="grid_12" id="servicesnav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">HCM</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SAP</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SuccessFactors</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

And here is the CSS code:

```
    .container_12 {
background: white;  
}

/*
**************
* =header
**************
*/

header img {
padding: 20px 0 20px 20px;
}

/*
**************
* =mainnav
**************
*/

#mainnav {
top: -3px;
background-color: #26719b;
font-size: 1.8em;
font-weight: bold;
margin-left: -20px;
margin-right: 0px;
width: 980px;
position:relative;
height:40px;
font-family: "Segoe UI";
padding: 0 0 0 20px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 10px;
}  


#mainnav ul li {
margin-right: 50px;
text-align: center;
display: inline;
}

#mainnav li a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
padding: 1px 16px 8px 16px;
}
nav li {
display: inline;
}

#mainnav li a:hover, .selected {
background: #f7a634;
border-radius: 5px;
}


/*
**************
* =subnavs
**************
*/

#servicesnav, #careernav, #clientsnav, #aboutnav  { 
font-size: 1.3em;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: #f7a634;
width: 430px;
height: 31px;
display: inline-block;
padding-top: 4px;
margin-top: -3px; 
border-radius: 10px;
}

#servicesnav li a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;      
}

#servicesnav ul li {
padding-top: 20px;
}

#careernav { 
margin-left: 180px;
}

#careernav li a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}

#careernav ul li {
padding-top: 20px;
margin-left: 80px;
}

#clientsnav { 
margin-left: 360px;
}

#clientsnav li a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;      
}

#clientsnav ul li {
padding-top: 20px;
margin-left: 90px;
}

#aboutnav { 
margin-left: 520px; 
}

#aboutnav li a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;      
}

#aboutnav ul li {
padding-top: 20px;
margin-left: 54px;
}

/*
**************
* =general
**************
*/

p, h1, h2, h3 {
font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
}

.sections h2 {
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 1.6em
}

/*
**************
* =main
**************
*/
.main .grid_8 {
margin-top: 20px;
}


/*
**************
* =services-->
**************
*/

#hcm, #sap, #successfactors, #support {
background-color: #26719b;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-left: -20px;
margin-right: 0px;
width: 980px;
height: 600px;
padding: 0 0 0 20px;
margin-top: 60px;
position:relative;
color: white;
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888888
}


#sap {
background-color: #f7a634;  
}


 #successfactors {
background-color: #26719b;
}


#support {
background-color: #f7a634;
}

/*
**************
* =career-->
**************
*/

#workingat, #jobs {
background-color: #26719b;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-left: -20px;
margin-right: 0px;
width: 980px;
height: 600px;
padding: 0 0 0 20px;
margin-top: 60px;
position:relative;
color: white;
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888888
}


#jobs {
background-color: #f7a634;  
}

/*
**************
* =clients-->
**************
*/

#clients, #testimonials {
background-color: #26719b;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-left: -20px;
margin-right: 0px;
width: 980px;
height: 600px;
padding: 0 0 0 20px;
margin-top: 60px;
position:relative;
color: white;
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888888
 }


#testimonials {
background-color: #f7a634;  
}

/*
**************
* =aboutus-->
**************
*/

#values, #partnerships, #contact {
background-color: #26719b;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-left: -20px;
margin-right: 0px;
width: 980px;
height: 600px;
padding: 0 0 0 20px;
margin-top: 60px;
position:relative;
color: white;
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888888
}


#partnerships {
background-color: #f7a634;  
}


 #contact {
background-color: #26719b;
```

Thank you very much!

--Edited to include more CSS code --

Comment: What is the issue? and Copy whole CSS here.

Comment: Do you mean like this? [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wpvhK/13/)

Comment: @Bindiya, I have copied the whole CSS thing now. I don't believe the bottom code will be relevant to this problem, but now the whole things is there :)

Comment: @ruddy, yes that is kinda it. I just need to have the logo as well. So it is the whole header - meaning logo, nav and sub nav.

Comment: @user3016496 That is holding the whole header at the top. [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/wpvhK/14/) I made it easier to see on this one.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put this in your css.

```
#mainnav {
    position:fixed;
}
```

Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/qxXXw/ and you also might want to have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp to get a better understanding about css positions, I know it took me awhile to figure it out at first.

Comment: I have tried that before. Just tried it again, but it just stays the same, so it is not fixed.

And yes, I think I need a better understanding of positionings as well :)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by fixed? Is this what you mean http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/? If so position:fixed is definitely what you are after, take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/gW4yN/ and see if it does what you want now.

Comment: Yes that is it. Your solution worked, so thank you! However this has given me another problem (I guess it is always so :) ). 

The text and content that scrolls up behind the header is visible behind the header as I scroll up, since some of the content boxes go beyond the 960 grid width and have a larger width than the header. Is this something you can help with as well or should I start another question?

Comment: Make a container around the header that is full width and then make the background of that container white? Is your site online? Because if it is it would make it a lot easier to give advice.

Comment: Thank you @joshhunt, I have done kinda what you suggest now and it works fine :)